# I need to get Subject name with total number of Book

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a SQL Query which I want to convert in Linq or want to show data
[as pictured here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRPVB.png)

Here is the query:

```
select sae_subcategorymaster.subject, count(sae_tblbookdetail.title) 
from sae_tblbookdetail inner join sae_subcategorymaster 
    on sae_subcategorymaster.subject=sae_tblbookdetail.subject 
group by sae_subcategorymaster.subject
```

What is a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Grouping is supported in LinqEF. Provided you have your entities related. (Books have a reference to their subcategory.)

```
var totals = context.Books
   .GroupBy(book => book.SubCategory.Subject)
   .Select(group => new 
   {
      Subject = group.Key,
      BookCount = group.Count()
   }).ToList();
```